# How do I update the syntax in Elasticsearch python client 8.5.3 where 'body' parameter is deprecated?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm using python to query and return data from Elasticsearch. Using ES 8.5.3 version. I have my Elasticsearch query stored in a parameter called "search_param" and using this parameter to search the index.

I was using the same script without any warning but coming across a 'deprecated' error lately, and I cant figure out how to make it work. The results appears but the warning is getting a bit annoying.

results = es.search(index="production-filebeat-*",  body = search_param)

Warning--"*DeprecationWarning: The 'body' parameter is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Instead use individual parameters.*"

I've tried using the 'Query' option instead but that gives me an error for my Lucene syntax. The same syntax works well with 'Body' parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As it said you can use separated parameter for each part of body. For example

```
resp = es.search(index="test-index", query={"match_all": {}})
```

If you have some specific query in mind, provide a minimal example of it in the question.